# MongoDB query not using the desired index

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am using the .Net SDK
I have a document with the following structure:

```
public class ChallengeComment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ChallengeId { get; set; }
    public long OwnerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChallengeCreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I have indexed using:

```
IMongoIndexKeys keys = new IndexKeysDocument {{ "OwnerID", 1 }, { "CreatedDateTime", 1 }, { "ChallengeCreatedDateTime", 1 } };
      IMongoIndexOptions options = IndexOptions.SetUnique(false);
_mongoDatabase.GetCollection("ChallengeComment").EnsureIndex(keys,options);
```

And the index has been successfully built

And I am performing the following query

```
var query =
          (from item in collection.AsQueryable<ChallengeComment>()
           where item.OwnerId == 162399
          orderby item.CreatedDateTime, item.ChallengeCreatedDateTime
          select item).Take(10);
```

however a full table scan is being performed.
I know that order matters in the index. I believe this is correct, though I may be mistaken.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OMG think I am about to shoot myself...

In the index I specified one of the keys as OwnerID
However in the query I used OwnerId
Lower case 'd'
Therefore it didn't use the correct index.

I won't make that mistake again!!!

Answer (score 0):

It should have been **`... where item.OwnerID = 162399`** instead of **`... where item.OwnerId`** in:

**Typo Version**

`var query =(from item in collection.AsQueryable<ChallengeComment>()`**`where item.OwnerId == 162399`** `orderby item.CreatedDateTime, item.ChallengeCreatedDateTime select item).Take(10);`

**Corrected Version**

```
var query =
          (from item in collection.AsQueryable<ChallengeComment>()
           where item.OwnerID == 162399
          orderby item.CreatedDateTime, item.ChallengeCreatedDateTime
          select item).Take(10);
```